# Scanning string for keywords of various lengths

Tags: java, arrays, search, hashmap, apache-poi

I want to scan my document split into array of words for certain keywords such as 'Fuel', 'Vehicle', 'Vehicle Leasing', 'Asset Type Maintenance' etc. The problem is that the keywords are of different lengths. One is a single word keyword, the other is 4 words keyword. At the moment I'm scanning word after word but that doesn't like the idea of multiple word keywords such as 'Vehicle Leasing' for example.

What can I do to improve my code and to work with multiple word keywords?
This is how it looks now

```
public void findKeywords(POITextExtractor te, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> listOfHashMaps, ArrayList<Integer> KeywordsFound, ArrayList<Integer> existingTags) {

    String document = te.getText().toString();
    String[] words = document.split("\\s+");
    int wordsNo = 0;
    int keywordsMatched = 0;

    try {
        for(String word : words) {
            wordsNo++;

            for(HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap : listOfHashMaps) {
                if(hashmap.containsKey(word) &&  !KeywordsFound.contains(hashmap.get(word)) && !existingTags.contains(hashmap.get(word))) {
                    KeywordsFound.add(hashmap.get(word));
                    keywordsMatched++;
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("New keywords found: " + KeywordsFound);
        System.out.println("Number of words in document = " + wordsNo);
        System.out.println("Number of keywords matched: " + keywordsMatched);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have included my method. If there's anything else required to understand my code, leave a comment please.

@UPDATE

```
public void findKeywords(POITextExtractor te, ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> listOfHashMaps, ArrayList<Integer> KeywordsFound, ArrayList<Integer> existingTags) {

    String document = te.getText().toString();
    String[] words = document.split("\\s+");
    int wordsNo = 0;
    int keywordsMatched = 0;

    for(HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap : listOfHashMaps) {
         Iterator it = hashmap.entrySet().iterator();
         while (it.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
             //System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
             it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

             if(document.contains((CharSequence) pair.getKey()) && !KeywordsFound.contains(pair.getValue()) && !existingTags.contains(pair.getValue())) {
                 System.out.println(pair.getKey());
                 KeywordsFound.add((Integer) pair.getValue());
                 keywordsMatched++;  
             }
         }
    }

    System.out.println("New keywords found: " + KeywordsFound);
    System.out.println("Number of keywords matched: " + keywordsMatched);
}
```

Comment: Why not use indexOf https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String) ? This can find multiple word for you. like `document.indexOf("Asset Type Maintenance");` This should return the index of the words found. You do not need to split the string for this.

Comment: I've done some testing and doing indexOf on a document for 3500 keywords isn't really efficient. It's been a lot quicker to scan every word against 3500 keywords and move on to the next one. That's why I've split it into words.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a kind of homework. Therefore: 
Have a look at [string search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) that search for a substring (pattern) in a larger string.

Then assume that you use one of this algorithms, but instead of having a sequence of chars (pattern) that you search for in a larger sequence of chars, you have a sequence of string (pattern) that you search for in a larger sequence of string. (so you just have a different, much larger, alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to split the string by the search strings.
eg.

```
List<String> searchString = new ArrayList<>();
searchString.add("Fuel");
searchString.add("Asset Type Maintenance");
searchString.add("Vehicle Leasing");

String document=""; // Assuming that you complete string is initilaized here.

for (String str : searchString) {
    String[] tempDoc=document.split(str);
    System.out.println(str + " is repated "+ (tempDoc.length-1) + " times");
```

Note this might thrash the JVM in garbage collection.
You can compare the performance on you own.

Comment: This was my original idea and it took so long for large file documents that it eventually run out of memory. Please look at my updated method.